# How to refer to current bean in spring expression language

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am using spring-3.2.2. I am new to spring and using the Spring Expression Language for the first time. Please consider the below snippet of spring configuration file in which I am facing the issue.

```
<bean id="bean3" class="com.springaction.testcollection.PersonBean">
        <property name="name"  value="Prakash" />
        <property name="age" value="62" />
        <property name="salary" value="30000" />
        <property name="bonus" value="#{salary*T(PersonBean).count}" />
   </bean>
```

In the above snippet, I want to use the salary field of the same bean(bean3) to calculate the bonus value. I just want to know how to refer the current bean's fields in the spring-configuration file? Is it possible?  If not are there any alternatives to  resolve the issue ?

Comment: Alternative: put the 'bonus' calculation logic in the 'salary' setter. Keep in mind that business logic in getters and setters is not the best practice. Also probably you constructor can set the salary, you need to implement the same there...

Comment: Thanks Evgeny for your answer.If I implement the InitializingBean interface in the PersonBean class and implement the Bonus calculation logic inside. Would that implementation would be a good practice ?

Comment: aside from avoiding what you want to do, have you tried value="@bean3.salary * @bean3.count". Using @ will resolve a bean in context. I don't know if this works within the same bean initialization phase. Just give it a try.